# Mount hfs+ partion

Tags: 12.04, mount, xubuntu, mac, hfs+

I want to mount a hfs+ partion on an external drive. I have installed `hfsprogs` and created a folder to mount at `/media/hfs`. Nevertheless this

```
# sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sdb2 /media/hfs

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

fails.

```
# dmesg | tail
[ 1778.517677] hfs: write access to a journaled filesystem is not supported, use the 
force option at your own risk, mounting read-only.
[ 1778.550769] hfs: invalid extent max_key_len 15237
[ 1778.550797] hfs: failed to load extents file
[ 1892.776860] hfs: write access to a journaled filesystem is not supported, use the 
force option at your own risk, mounting read-only.
[ 1892.777288] hfs: invalid extent max_key_len 15237
[ 1892.777297] hfs: failed to load extents file
```

I am certain that `/dev/sdb2` is correct because I checked it with `gparted`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the partition is either not formatted, formatted from a recent `OSX` version with options currently unknown to the `hfs+` driver, or needing a repair.

In the case of an unformatted partition, `gparted` will see it correctly as `HFS+` because it's just a flag in the partition table.

In case of needing a repair, just plug the disk into an OSX machine, run `Disk Utility` and use the `repair` button (bottom right, after you selected the partition in the side pane).

I'm not aware of any recent HFS+ options not understood by the `HFS+` driver, but it has happened in the past. The only solution in this case is to wait.