# mount apple filesystem using fsapfsmount

Tags: mount, filesystem, apple

I'm trying to mount a 5TB external USB disk into an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Among other things the utility expects a container with the apple FS and a mount point.
Maybe I should mention that it is an encrypted filesystem.

Anyway, the first attempt to mount yielded:

```
root@kuku-Lenovo-Y70-70-Touch:~# fsapfsmount /dev/sdb /media/Volumes
fsapfsmount 20190210

Unable to open source container
libfsapfs_container_superblock_read_data: invalid object type: 0x00000000.
libfsapfs_container_superblock_read_file_io_handle: unable to read container superblock data.
libfsapfs_internal_container_open_read: unable to read container superblock at offset: 0 (0x00000000).
libfsapfs_container_open_file_io_handle: unable to read from file IO handle.
mount_handle_open: unable to open container.

root@kuku-Lenovo-Y70-70-Touch:~# fdisk /dev/sdb

Willkommen bei fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Änderungen werden vorerst nur im Speicher vorgenommen, bis Sie sich
entscheiden, sie zu schreiben.
Seien Sie vorsichtig, bevor Sie den Schreibbefehl anwenden.

GPT-PMBR-Größenunterschied (4294967294 != 9767475199) wird durch »write« korrigiert.

Befehl (m für Hilfe): p

Festplatte /dev/sdb: 4,56 TiB, 5000947302400 Bytes, 9767475200 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: Elements 2620   
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: A2BXXXF3-DXX4-4XXX-AEA8-803934XXXXXX

Gerät          Anfang       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdb1          40     409639     409600  200M EFI-System
/dev/sdb2      409640 9767213015 9766803376  4,6T Apple Core Speicher
/dev/sdb3  9767213016 9767475159     262144  128M Apple Boot

Befehl (m für Hilfe):
```

Trying to specify an offset, e.g. 409640, also fails.
WHat may I be doing wrong?

Another thing is the GPT-PMBR size difference being claimed. I don't understand that. The disk has been generated as an encrypted Volume on a macOS 10.15.6.

Comment: The answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038816/how-do-i-mount-a-gpt-drive-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts might work for you even though it's older.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? i have a similar problem. you said that it was encrypted and there is a password flag in your example. mine is not encrypted though so i don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mount an encrypted volume without supplying a password.

`fsapfsmount -p <password> <source>`

The instructions are clear in `man fsapfsmount`